# Item with the Same Key Already Added (SQL)

Tags: sql, visual-studio, reporting-services

I'm having a problem with some SQL I'm writing. Whilst I know the Error means that I have referenced the same column twice I can't seem to find where. It runs fine in SQL Server Management but when I try to put it into Visual Studio to create a report from it, it gives me the error.

Here is my code:

```
SELECT 
    TC.CorrespondanceName1
    , LC.Address1
    , LC.Address2
    , LC.Address3
    , LC.Address4
    , LC.PostCode
    , TC.Telephone
    , (DATEDIFF(yy,PC.DateofBirth,GetDate()) - (CASE WHEN GetDate() < DATEADD(yy,DATEDIFF(yy,PC.DateofBirth,GetDate()), PC.DateofBirth) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)) AS Age
    , CASE WHEN PAC.AttribCode = 'CON1' AND PAC.LogValue = 1 THEN 'Yes' ELSE 'No' END AS [Telephone]
    , CASE WHEN PAC.AttribCode = 'CON2' AND PAC.LogValue = 1 THEN 'Yes' ELSE 'No' END AS [Post]
    , CASE WHEN PAC.AttribCode = 'CON3' AND PAC.LogValue = 1 THEN 'Yes' ELSE 'No' END AS [Email]
    , CASE WHEN PAC.AttribCode = 'CON4' AND PAC.LogValue = 1 THEN 'Yes' ELSE 'No' END AS [Text]
    , CASE WHEN PAC.AttribCode = 'CON5' AND PAC.LogValue = 1 THEN 'Yes' ELSE 'No' END AS [Facebook]
    , CASE WHEN PAC.AttribCode = 'CON6' AND PAC.LogValue = 1 THEN 'Yes' ELSE 'No' END AS [Website]
    , CASE WHEN PAC.AttribCode = 'CON7' AND PAC.LogValue = 1 THEN 'Yes' ELSE 'No' END AS [Meeting]
FROM 
    vwTenancyCurrent TC 
INNER JOIN
    vwLocationCurrent LC ON LC.PlaceRef = TC.PlaceRef 
INNER JOIN
    vwTenancyPersonCurrent TPC ON TPC.TenancySystemRef = TC.TenancySystemRef 
INNER JOIN
    vwPersonCurrent PC ON PC.PersonRef = TPC.PersonRef 
INNER JOIN
    vwPersonAttributesCurrent PAC ON PAC.PersonRef = PC.PersonRef 
WHERE 
    TC.TenancyStatus <> 'FOR'
    AND PC.DateofBirth <> ''
```

I've done some digging and the error definitely relates to my `Case` statements but I've used the `Case` statement this way before and never had this problem.

Can anyone help?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `Telephone` column appears twice in your query.

SSMS can handle a query with multiple identical column names but you can't use such a query in a Report.
This is by design, column names are used as a key.

Rename 1 of them and the problem will go away.

Comment: Hey, thanks for a speedy response. Not sure how I didn't notice I'd made a column Alias as the same name as an actual column (fresh set of eyes is always helpful) . Thanks

Comment: @Wilks3y - No problem, I'm used to this error so already knew where to look at :)

Answer (score 2):

```
TC.Telephone,
, CASE WHEN PAC.AttribCode = 'CON1' AND PAC.LogValue = 1 
         THEN 'Yes' ELSE 'No' 
  END AS `[Telephone]`
```

Change second alias as something another name `Telephone_home` etc.. then your code will work